# Query to show all months and show values where there are data for the corresponding months

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `query` and it shows the months where there is corresponding data. However, I would like to show all of the months in the year and have the months where there are no data shown as zero.

There is my SQL Statement:

```
SELECT   DATENAME(MONTH, hb_Disputes.OPENED) AS MonthValue, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN REV_CLS = 2 THEN 1 END) AS SmallCommercialIndust, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN REV_CLS <> 2 THEN 1 END) AS Residential
FROM         hb_Disputes
WHERE     (hb_Disputes.ASSGNTO = 'E099255') AND (YEAR(hb_Disputes.OPENED) = YEAR(GETDATE()))
GROUP BY hb_Disputes.OPENED
```

And this is my output:

[image]

I also have a table name `MonthName` that shows all of the months in a year and I know I may need to use this to accomplish what I'm trying to achieve but I'm not sure how to get there:

[image]

Comment: Be great if you could stop using images and instead use formatted text for queries and data.

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have data in the table for all months, but the `where` clause is filtering it out, then the simplest method is to extend the conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, d.OPENED) AS MonthValue, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN d.ASSGNTO = 'E099255' AND d.REV_CLS = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SmallCommercialIndust, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN d.ASSGNTO = 'E099255' AND d.REV_CLS <> 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Residential
FROM hb_Disputes d
WHERE YEAR(d.OPENED) = YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, d.OPENED) 
ORDER BY MIN(d.OPENED);
```

Note:  This does not fix the issue in all cases.  It should just be a simple way to modify your query -- and will often work.